# Transaction handling in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to apache camel. I am developing an integration application using camel with Oracle Weblogic as JEE container. In that we get an request from upstream system over jms, we need to transform the request and persist it in database and send it to another system as well over jms. Goal is to rollback the transaction even if either of the above operations fails(persist to DB or sending to a jms queue). Below is the sample route definition.

```
from("weblogicJMS:OEP_SALESORDER_JMS_QUEUE?exchangePattern=InOnly").unmarshal(jaxb).process(new ProcessSalesOrderFulfillmentProcessor());

from("direct:saveOrderToRespository").to("jpa:com.xyz.oep.order.presistence.model.OepOrder");       

from("direct:sendSalesOrderEBMToOSM?exchangePattern=InOnly").to("weblogicJMS:OEP_OSM_WS_REQUEST_QUEUE_JNDI");
```

In process method of ProcessSalesOrderFulfillmentProcessor 
I handling the calls to direct:sendSalesOrderEBMToOSM route and direct:saveOrderToRespository route.

I am looking for some best practices or suggestions to implement transaction for above routes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, there is no simple "Add transaction to my code". Transactions are really complex. You need design, that fits to your specific needs. For simpliest usage look [HERE](http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html) and [HERE](http://camel.apache.org/transactionerrorhandler.html) . For extended tutorials I would suggest read Chapter 12 in book [Camel in Action, Second Edition](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition)

Comment: I only have experience of working with the JBoss Fuse platform, so I can't tell you how you would implement it on Weblogic. But to add to what Bedla has already said I suggest you read up on XA Transactions as you will need that in order to have your transactions span over multiple participating systems (such as database and JMS). Incidentally I found [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-5892/ref_xatrans/index.html) for XA Transactions and Weblogic.